# Node and MongoDB with Express and Mongoose error handler issue using 'mongoose-unique-validator'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to use *'mongoose-unique-validator'* for handling Mongo ValidationError more easily. The issue comes when I try to force a ValidationError and it doesn't even enters into my custom error handler. Any other error works properly, but not this one.

**I just want the validator to send a response JSON so the client app can see what field is wrong/not unique.**

#### handleErrors.js

```js
const ERROR_HANDLERS = {
    // Example handler that actually works.
    JsonWebTokenError: (res) => res.status(401).json({ error: 'Token missing or invalid' }),

    // Handler that is not working
    ValidationError: (res, { message }) => res.status(409).json({ error: message }),
};

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
    const handler = ERROR_HANDLERS[err.name];

    handler(res, err);
};
```

#### User.js

```js
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        uniqueCaseInsensitive: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
    },
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = {
    User: model('User', UserSchema),
};
```

#### index.js

```js
app.use(appRouter);
app.use('/api/users', userRouter);

app.use(notFound);
app.use(handleErrors);
```

#### userRouter.js

```js
const usersRouter = require('express').Router();

const userController = require('../controllers/userController');

usersRouter.get('/', userController.listAll);

usersRouter.post('/', userController.create);

module.exports = usersRouter;
```

#### userController.js

```js
create: async (req, res) => {
        const { body } = req;

        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, 10);

        const user = new User({
            ...body,
            passwordHash,
        });

        const savedUser = await user.save();

        res.status(201).send(savedUser);
    },
```

#### Console output on ValidationError trigger

```
DB connected
(node:8728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Error, expected `username` to be unique. Value: `user2`, email: Error, expected `email` to be unique. Value: `user2@email.com`
    at model.Document.invalidate (x\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2704:32)
    at x\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2524:17
    at x\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1241:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
(node:8728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Can you add your `userRouter.js` file also output of `console.log(err)`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar done! userRouter.js added.

I didn't add console.log(err) btw because it simply won't run on the errors handler when the error is a ValidationError, but it does when it is another error.name.

I mean, if the error is a ValidationError, it won't even step into the handler and just throws the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on the console.

Comment: Please add code of `userController.create` function .

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `const savedUser = await user.save();` in try-catch block to capture the error and handle error in the catch block.

```
create: async (req, res, next) => {
        const { body } = req;
        const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, 10);
        const user = new User({
            ...body,
            passwordHash,
        });
        try {
            const savedUser = await user.save();
            res.status(201).send(savedUser);
        }  catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          next(error);
          // throw error; // you can throw error
          // res.status(422).send({ 'message': 'Validation error' }); // handle your error here
        }
    },
```

Comment: Sure, but I want to handle the error using the ERROR_HANDLER module, will this solution trigger that middleware?

Comment: @JMRBDev add `next` and call `next(error);` https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html